# Fourier transform of area between four circles

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Four similar circles (radius-$R$) are packed in a simple square structure. Let's denote the area between these circles as $S$ - 
[red area in attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkArl.png).

Now, let's think about a function $f$ that takes a value of $1$ inside $S$ and $0$ outside of $S$. No periodic boundary conditions are assumed.
what analytical function describes the Fourier transform of $f$?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiWw0.png) is a numerical solution (magnitude in log scale) obtained using Python.

Comment: Fourier transforms apply to real-valued functions. Is your function 1 on the red area and 0 on the blue area, perhaps? And are you looking for the Fourier transform on $S^1 \times S^1$, or on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, where the function is defined to be $0$ outside the unit square?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by Fourier transform of an area?

Comment: Do you consider "periodic boundary condition"? i.e. is the right border equivalent to the left? Then your solution would most certainly be linked to Bessel functions.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question as John Hughes and Rajesh Dachiraju suggested.

Comment: @atrash : Are you working in $R^3$? you mean to say cubic, hence this question.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju yes I am working in R3.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju These actually cylinders. Maybe it is better to change cubic to square.

Comment: If you're in $R^3$, then "circles" don't pack cubically -- spheres do (or perhaps cylinders). And you still need to answer the question: periodic boundary condition? Or zero outside this square? Without the answer to that, we cannot help you.

Comment: @JohnHughes and @ the_architect No periodic boundary condition. i.e. zero outside this square.

Comment: @atrash : In your numerical solution, What is it that you are showing in the picture? The magnitude? or the phase?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju The solution shows the magnitude in log scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraunhofer diffraction of aperture $S$ by means of Fourier Transform:

\begin{align*}
  F(\mathbf{k}) &=
  \iint_S f(x,y)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}} \, dA \\ &=
  \int_{-R}^{0} e^{ik_x x} dx 
  \left(
    \int_{-R+\sqrt{-2Rx-x^2}}^{R-\sqrt{-2Rx-x^2}} e^{ik_y y} \,dy
  \right) \\
  &\quad +\int_{0}^{R} e^{ik_x x}  dx
  \left(
    \int_{-R+\sqrt{2Rx-x^2}}^{R-\sqrt{2Rx-x^2}} e^{ik_y y}  dy
  \right) \\ &=
  \int_{-R}^{0}
  2\sin \left[k_y \left( \sqrt{-2Rx-x^2}-R \right) \right]
  \frac{e^{ik_x x}}{k_y} \, dx \\
  & \quad +
  \int_{0}^{R}
  2\sin \left[k_y \left( \sqrt{2Rx-x^2}-R \right) \right]
  \frac{e^{ik_x x}}{k_y} \, dx \\ &=
  4 \int_{0}^{R}
  \sin \left[k_y \left( \sqrt{2Rx-x^2}-R \right) \right]
  \frac{\cos k_x x}{k_y} \, dx
\end{align*}

The integral doesn't have close form.

Comment: $f(x,y) = 1_{x^2+y^2 < R^2} $  ? You should get a Bessel function for $F(k)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Two-dimensional_functions

Comment: It's not a circle but looks like an astroid.

Comment: @NgChungTak Thank you very much !